# Django development server on LAN

Tags: python, django, server, lan

It's my first time creating a django project. Now I'm at the point where I need to run the development server in the **LAN**. Except I can't get it to work.

My computer is connected with ethernet and the other computers in the network are connected via Wifi don''t know if that's relevant though.

What I tried by running the following:
The ip adress I found using `ifconfig` and copying  inet addr: under ens33.

```
- python manage.py runserver myipadrres:8000
- python manage,py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The 0.0.0.0 doesn't even work on the windows os on my own computer. The ipadress does work for that.

Django settings debug is set to True.

Like I said it's the first time creating such a project and I don't know much about web related stuff. So I might have forgot to install something that I don''t know about.

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT:
Managed to get it working i just had to turn on bridged networking in my VM settings

Greetings,
Dani

Answer (score 2):

If that setup is working on your localmachine then 
Just use that localmachine Ip:port-number in your LAN pc as:

for example :

If local machine Ip  = 192.168.6.25 and setup is running on 8000 port ,then open browser at LAN machine PC and use this:

```
192.168.6.25:8000
```

Even you can run the setup on different port by this command

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<your_port>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly (Sorry if i'm being stupid i just don't know anything about these things). Do i need to run manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000 and then use another computer in lan with my pc ip4adress?

Comment: @Dani as  you said you want to run your development server on other Pc via LAN. So Please read the answer and revert back if any query